# Compiling V8 on Windows to Use with g++

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, v8

I have gone through all the procedures on how to compile V8 and actually managed to compile it on Windows platform. However, the problem is that the compilation procedure on Windows forces you to compile with Visual Studio and therefore creates object files (.obj) which can be used in VS. I have managed to create a DLL file too but it only serves the purpose when there is an executable to run.

On the other hand, I am using Eclipse and g++ on Windows. To embed V8 into my C++ I will need to have a library file (.a extension so that the linker will work). Is there a way that this is doable?

Answer (score 0):

When the DLL was created an import library should have been created as well. They typically have the same name as the DLL but with a `.lib` extension. Add this library to your project in Eclipse and it should be linked in at build time. you can do this by right clicking on the project and selecting `Properties -> C/C++ Build` then go `Library` and add it there.

Comment: Hi it is still not linking.
Eclipse use the command as follows:
    g++ "-LC:\\Users\\ml\\workspace\\MyCPPStudies" -lpthread -o MyCPPStudies.exe v8deneme.o -lv8 -lv8_nosnapshot.ia32 -lv8_snapshot -lv8_base.ia32

Comment: The linker says:
v8deneme.o:v8deneme.cpp:(.text.startup+0x12): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
and for other functions as well.

Comment: I have even used lib2a tool and converted obj, dll and def file to .a and still no luck. I should be doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you check to make sure the DLL is actually exporting those symbols? Did you check to make sure the generated library contains those symbols? If the `.a` file is valid and the linker is using it then chances the symbols are not exported or the conversion failed successfully.

Comment: It seems that libv8.a has it. I used the nm utility and here is the result:
dgpbs00248.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 i .idata$4
00000000 i .idata$5
00000000 i .idata$6
00000000 i .idata$7
00000000 t .text
00000000 T ?GetCurrent@Isolate@v8@@SAPAV12@XZ
         U __head_v8_a
00000000 I __imp_?GetCurrent@Isolate@v8@@SAPAV12@XZ

Here we see GetCurrent() is already there. So why could the linker be complaining?

Comment: One more thing which might be important: when I use the nm utility for v8.dll it says no symbols for v8.dll.

Comment: @macroland The means the symbols are not being exported. Check your project to make sure that proper macro is defined in the preprocessor settings. For for instance `BASE_IMPLEMENTATION` must be defined to export symbols from the base module (src/base). `BASE_IMPLEMENTATION` must **not** be defined in other modules in order to import symbols from the dll, this is the default which is why it's trying to link to those symbols.